# Text Import Window suppression when importing CSV Data in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc

In LibreOffice, when one imports a .CSV File within Calc, one obtains a Dialog named “Text Import”, in which one can select several options, including the “Separated By” Option (where one could select “comma” for instance). It appears that the Software does not allow one to suppress the display of this Window, and set the “Comma” option as the default one (similar to what is done in Excel). Thus, how could I set the option to “comma” and suppress the Dialog in code?

Comment: You want to suppress that dialogue "in code" - so you need a solution that works in a macro?

Comment: @tbodt Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @KnocksX No. I'm trying to burninate the [tag:calc] tag.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask the OP, @JF0001